# Macro Signature Not Honored by Velocity Engine

Tags: macros, velocity

How can I enable Velocity engine to honor  #macro signatures so that if I try calling a macro in templates Example:

```
#myTestMacro($arg1 $arg2)
```

that has a different signature when defined Example:

```
#macro(myTestMacro $arg)
```

Velocity will be smart enough to throw an error, so I can catch invalid number of arguments in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration, set `velocimacro.arguments.strict=true`.